# c# download file stream performance problem

Tags: c#, xamarin, stream, dotnet-httpclient, system.io.file

I want to download a file from a GET HTTP REQUEST response. To download the stream i use `HttpClient` like this sample :

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using ModernHttpClient;

var exClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(method), "https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin");
HttpResponseMessage response = await exClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

I want to save the file to disk, so i use `System.IO`.

First i use this code :

```
using IOFile = System.IO.File;

Stream file = IOFile.Open(path, FileMode.Create);
contentStream.CopyTo(file);
file.close;
```

But i also wanted to get informations about the download progression, so i switch to this code :

```
using IOFile = System.IO.File;

Stream file = IOFile.Open(path, FileMode.Create);

var buffer = new byte[81920];
int received = 0;
int read = 0;

while ((read = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    file.Write(buffer, 0, read);

    received += read;

    //progressCallback?.Invoke(received);
}

file.Close();
```

My problem is that the download time becomes more than twice as long as with the `CopyTo` method (about 30Mbit/s against ~90 for CopyTo).

What explains this difference? How do I get closer to CopyTo's performance?

Comment: Use the non-async Read method and place the download routine in its own thread (Task.Run or new Thread....)

Comment: I have placed all the code, the request and the file writing under the same Task.Run, without ReadAsync I still don't reach the desired speed, this method just makes the download speed more unstable, it varies a lot between > 18 and 30 < mbits